# Error al ejecutar aplicacion C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una aplicacion en Visual Studio pero al ejecutar me sale el siguiente mensaje de error

```
An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\Lotes.exe. SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.    Lotes
```

alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Podrias especificar un poco mas que es ese ejecutable? estas tratando de instalar un programa firmado con click once?

Comment: aporta algo mas de contexto, por el nombre de la carpeta al tener `publish` esta claro que se produce al generar el instalador, pero que tool usas para esto?